# Tags / placeholder in WYSIWYG (Redactor)

Tags: jquery, tags, wysiwyg, redactor, redactor.js

I am working on a mail system to send mass emails.
I made a plugin for redactor which adds a tag to eg. first name.
These tags should not be edited by the user, only deleted.

My problem is that every time I get the code with this.code.get (), its cleaning the code and will not return my "tags". And the text in the tag is also editable.

Are there some who have done this before or know how to do it?

if it can be done with another WYSIWYG then i'm open for change.

**Init redactor :**

```
$("#redactor").redactor({
            buttons: ['html', 'formatting', 'bold', 'italic',
                'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'alignment'],
            plugins: ['tags'],
            toolbarExternal: toolbar,
            allowedTags: ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'pre', 'div', 'span'],
            iframe: true,
            keydownCallback: function(e)
            {
                console.log(this.code.get());
            },
            startCallback: function () {
              ...
            },
            destroyCallback: function () {
              ...
            },
            blurCallback: function (e) {
               ...
            }
        })
```

**The plugin**

```
var fields = {
    "first_name" : "First name",
    "last_name" : "Last name",
    "e_mail" : "E-mail"
}

RedactorPlugins.tags = function()
{
    return {
        init: function ()
        {
            var dropdown = {};
            var redactor = this;
            $.each(fields, function( key, value ) {
                dropdown[key] = { title: value , func: redactor.tags.pointFirstCallback };
            });

            var button = this.button.add('fields', 'tags');

            this.button.addDropdown(button, dropdown);
        },
        pointFirstCallback: function(buttonName)
        {
            this.insert.html('<span field="'+buttonName+'" class="tag">'+fields[buttonName]+'</span> ', false);
        }

    };
};
```

**How its should look like in the editor**

[image: Tags example]

Comment: I'm working on a similar challenge. I came across this for Redactor 8 and 9: https://github.com/Zmetser/Placeholder-for-Redactor but I can't find anything similar for Redactor 10. Did you find a good solution?

Comment: Hey @JonnyWhite . 
I made my own plugin . I will post it in a answer soon :)

Comment: @ThomasBolander Did you manage to write a plugin for Redactor (maybe for version 10)?

Comment: @splattne I have now posted my solution.. If something doesnt make sense, let me know.. I have copied it out of my content, so it couldt look a little ugly for other people :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like version 10 of Redactor, am I right?

Comment: @splattne No problem - Yes :)

Comment: @splattne and thank you for the edit of my answer :) Good luck :)

Comment: Your approach looks promising. I'll let you know as soon as I have time to test it in my appplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (Not a pretty one, but a solution...)

```
var fields = {};
fields["field_first_name"] = "First name";        
fields["field_last_name"] = "Last name";
fields["field_e_mail"] = "E-mail";


RedactorPlugins.tags = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            var dropdown = {};
            var redactor = this;
            $.each(fields, function (key, value) {
                dropdown[key] = {title: value, func: redactor.tags.tagsCallback};
            });

            var button = this.button.add('fields', 'Shortcodes');

            this.button.addDropdown(button, dropdown);
        },
        tagsCallback: function (buttonName) {
            var elem;
            if ($(this.selection.getParent()).is(".tag, span.tag"))
                elem = $(this.selection.getParent());
            else
                elem = $(this.selection.getCurrent())

            if ($(elem).is(".tag")) {
                this.caret.setAfter($(elem));
                this.insert.text(" ");
            }

            var node = $('<samp />').attr("title", fields[buttonName]).addClass("tag").attr("field_id", buttonName).text(fields[buttonName]);
            this.insert.node(node);
            this.caret.setAfter(node);
            this.code.sync();
        }

    };
};
```

Init redactor

```
$("editor").redactor({
  buttons: ['formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'alignment', 'link'],
  plugins: ['tags', 'fontsize', 'fontcolor', 'underline'],
  allowedTags: ['u', 'span', 'p', 'a', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'pre', "samp", "strong", "em", "li", "ul", "ol", "br"],

  keydownCallback: function (e) {
    var elem;
    if ($(this.selection.getParent()).is(".tag, f"))
      elem = $(this.selection.getParent());
    else
      elem = $(this.selection.getCurrent())

    if ($(elem).is(".tag") && (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)) {
      $(elem).remove();
    }
    else if ($(elem).is(".tag")) {
      this.caret.setAfter($(elem));
    }

    if ($(elem).is(".tag") && (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40)) {
      if (e.keyCode == 37)
        this.caret.setBefore($(elem));
      else
        this.caret.setAfter($(elem));
    }

    if ($(elem).is(".tag")) {
      $(elem).text($(elem).attr("title"));
    }
  },

  keyupCallback: function (e) {
    var elem;
    if ($(this.selection.getParent()).is(".tag"))
      elem = $(this.selection.getParent());
    else
      elem = $(this.selection.getCurrent())


    if ($(elem).is(".tag") && (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(elem).remove();

    }
    else if ($(elem).is(".tag")) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.caret.setAfter($(elem));
    }

    if ($(elem).is(".tag") && (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.keyCode == 37)
        this.caret.setBefore($(elem));
      else
        this.caret.setAfter($(elem));
    }

    if ($(elem).is(".tag")) {
      $(elem).text($(elem).attr("title"));
    }
  },

  clickCallback: function (e) {
    var elem;
    if ($(this.selection.getParent()).is(".tag"))
      elem = $(this.selection.getParent());
    else
      elem = $(this.selection.getCurrent())


    if ($(elem).is(".tag")) {
      this.caret.setAfter($(this.selection.getCurrent()));
    }
  },

  changeCallback: function () {
    $("samp.tag").each(function () {
      if ($(this).attr("title") !== $(this).text())
        $(this).remove();
    })
    this.code.sync();
  },

  blurCallback: function (e) {
    $("samp.tag").each(function () {
      if ($(this).attr("title") !== $(this).text())
        $(this).remove();
    })
    this.code.sync();
  }
});
```